# .Resources file "extraction"?

Tags: c#, resources

I have a project I was working on and a few weeks ago I had to restore my PC, I opened up the project today only to see I don't have all the images because it was all on my desktop. I have a load of files I didn't see before that are called things like "frmMain.resources", I'm assuming all the images in my project are in those files. Is there any way I could view these files and extract my image files out?

Thanks in advance

-Neel

Comment: You can recover them with the ResourceReader class.

Comment: May I suggest you invest in some source control software; git is server-less and you can push to a file share (remote) to keep backups of your source code

Comment: You may also find that tools such as ILSpy or Reflector will help you work out the names of the resources in those files.

Comment: I have the source code, I backed up my project but I didn't back up my images

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) but it seems the latest version has the ability to save the resources from an assembly, requiring no extra tools.